# foreach=> delete(element)- shows me this.data.recipe.ingredientList.delete is not a function

Tags: angular

i'm trying to delete a list in angular but it sends me a mistake - can someone please help me?

```
    ERROR TypeError: _this.data.recipe.ingredientList.delete is not a function
    at add-recipe.component.ts:110
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at AddRecipeComponent.push../src/app/components/HomePage/dialog/add-recipe/add-recipe.component.ts.AddRecipeComponent.saveEdition (add-recipe.component.ts:109)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (AddRecipeComponent.html:87)
    at handleEvent (core.js:10251)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11344)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:11047)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:7710)
    at core.js:8154
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:988)
```

code in ts

```js
      this.ingr = this.data.recipe.ingredientList;
    this.data.recipe.ingredientList.forEach(element => {
      this.data.recipe.ingredientList.delete(element);
    });
```

Comment: I guess ingredientList is not an Array but an Object.

Comment: Seems like you want to clear the list, in that case you could just do `this.data.recipe.ingredientList = []`

Comment: @JulienGabriel but then `.foreach` would also throw an error

Comment: if its an array , then try the delete method using splice() function.

Comment: @aomerk Hard to say according to the given sample. May be there is a try catch wrapping it...

Comment: @JulienGabriel btw, is there even a `.delete()` method? i mean either for an object or an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1: You could just reset the array, supposing this is an array

```
this.data.recipe.ingredientList = []
```

2: If you want to delete elements from an array, you can use index parameter of foreach, because you are trying to delete an element from array. This one is just to correct your approach, please use the first option if that satisfies your needs.

```
this.ingredientList.forEach((element, index) => {
    this.ingredientList.splice(index,1);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> 'delete' is not a function : Because there's no delete function on javascript array
> ```
>
> For deleting an element in an Array object, you can use splice() or filter() predefined javascript function

Here's an example using filter() :

```js
 countyCode =  [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    
    console.log(countyCode.filter( element => {return element !== 5}));
```

Answer (score 0):

1) first of all you have to cross-check that whether the declared ingredientList variable is an array or not. If it won't be an array then you can't use the array functions.

2) Also, the delete is not an array function. to delete/remove an element from the array you can use splice function.

```
this.ingredientList.forEach(i => {
  const index = this.ingredientList.indexOf(i)
  this.ingredientList.splice(index,1);
})
```

Comment: the param `i` is actually the element, you should get parameters `(element,i)` and then use `i`